# Angularfire - How Do You Test a $watch Callback?

Tags: firebase, jasmine, angularfire

AngularFire has its own `$watch` callback method that can be attached to an instance of `$firebaseArray`.

If I have something like:

```
$scope.registerAngularFireWatch = function(){
    $scope.angularFireArray.$watch(function(data){
        $scope.myVariable = true;
        $scope.anotherVariable = data;
    });
};
```

How do I write a Jasmine test to trigger the `$watch` in this instance?

Answer (score -1):

You should mock the `$firebaseArray` service and create a spy for the `$watch` function:

```
var firebaseArrayMock = function () {
  return {
    $watch: jasmine.createSpy()
  };
};
var controller;
// ...
beforeEach(function () {
  controller = $controller('yourController', {
    $firebaseArray: firebaseArrayMock
  });
});
```

Then you can expect for it to be called:

```
expect(firebaseArrayMock.$watch).toBeCalled();
```